# Regular expressions PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Hi I am trying to use preg_match_all() to extract the number in bold out of an image URL...

http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/174844_**39677118233**_8277870_t.jpg

Could someone please help me with the regular expression needed as I am stumped.

I've used this so far:

```
preg_match_all("(http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/.*_t.jpg)siU", $this->html, $matching_data);
return $matching_data[0];
}
```

Which is just giving me an array of the full links.

Hope someone can help, thanks!!!

Comment: If you are trying to use `preg_match_all`, where is your code?

Comment: Do you have another example URL?  Do all of the file names have the same number of underscores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you all occurrences:

```
$matches = preg_match_all ('!/hprofile-ak-snc4/[0-9]+_([0-9]+)[^/]+?\.jpg!i', $txt);
print_r ($matches);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have 5 of these links on a page and I wanted preg_match_all to go through them. I've just tried the above and I get /174844_39677118233_8277870_t.jpg with preg_match_all. What makes it harder is that some other links have the same numbering format but its only the links that have hprofile-ak-snc4/ as a prefix i'm interested in... Thanks for the help so far!!!

Comment: @Greg Reed I modified the pattern according to your comment.

Comment: I used this - $uri = "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/174844_39677118233_8277870_t.jpg";
$matches = preg_match ('!/[0-9]+_([0-9]+)[^/]+?\.jpg!i', $uri);
echo ($matches[3]);    // will be: 39677118233

Answer (score 1):

Number you have bolded should be contained in `$matches[$n][3]`...

```
preg_match_all("#http://profile\.ak\.fbcdn\.net/(.*?)/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_t\.jpg#is", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*:(//[^/?#]+)?)?
([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/]*)
(?:(?:\d+_)(\d+)(?:_\d+))\3
```

I've separated it out onto multiple lines for easier reading.  You will want to use capture group 4

Or (just minimized it a bit)

```
(?:[a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*:(?://[^/?#]+)?)?
([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/]*)
(?:(?:\d+_)(\d+)(?:_\d+))\1
```

and use capture group 2